# How to use angular cli schematics that are not the defaults one?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-akita, akita

I've an Ionic application. I now want to use [Akita](https://github.com/datorama/akita) as state management in my project.
By default, Akita tries to replaces

```
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
  },
```

by

```
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@datorama/akita"
  },
```

and it extends the angular actions. My issue is that it won't extends the default Ionic schematics.

So I did preferred to keep the `@ionic/angular-toolkit` and have to specify the akita schematics when I want to use them.

But now if I try something like:

```
ng g akita-schematics:as auth/auth
```

I get an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Collection "akita-schematics" cannot
>   be resolved.

So my question is, how can I add an angular schematics(for akita, but I guess it's the same for other libraries), without setting it as default?

Comment: Try ng g @datoram/akita:as auth/auth

Comment: the above command worked for me

Comment: ```@datorama``` instead of ```@datoram``` so the final command is: ```ng g @datorama/akita:as auth/auth```